# Digital RGB LED animation

Tags: programming, led

I've been trying to get colours fade into each other for a project I'm working on.
I have achieved this with the rainbow effect that some from Adafruit's example code, however I want to be able to choose the colours (eg. dark blue into light blue).

I've got the colours changing and fading, however the fade turns off all the LEDs and starts to increase the brightness of the new colour. I need the colours to blend rather than fade out and increase in brightness.

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction?

```
#include "LPD8806.h"
#include "SPI.h"
#define stripSize 64

int nLEDs = 160;

int dataPin  = 2;
int clockPin = 3;

// First parameter is the number of LEDs in the strand.  The LED strips
// are 32 LEDs per meter but you can extend or cut the strip.  Next two
// parameters are SPI data and clock pins:
LPD8806 strip = LPD8806(64, dataPin, clockPin);

// You can optionally use hardware SPI for faster writes, just leave out
// the data and clock pin parameters.  But this does limit use to very
// specific pins on the Arduino.  For "classic" Arduinos (Uno, Duemilanove,
// etc.), data = pin 11, clock = pin 13.  For Arduino Mega, data = pin 51,
// clock = pin 52.  For 32u4 Breakout Board+ and Teensy, data = pin B2,
// clock = pin B1.  For Leonardo, this can ONLY be done on the ICSP pins.
//LPD8806 strip = LPD8806(nLEDs);

void setup() {
  // Start up the LED strip
  strip.begin();

  // Update the strip, to start they are all 'off'
  strip.show();
}

void loop() {
  //turnAllOn(strip.Color(30,30,30),4000);
  fade(0, 127, 0, 100); //red, green, blue, delay - fade up all pixels one color
  //turnAllOn(strip.Color(30,100,30),4000);
  fade(50, 127, 02,100); //red, green, blue, delay - fade up all pixels one color
  //turnAllOn(strip.Color(100,30,100),4000);
  fade(50, 127, 50, 100); //red, green, blue, delay - fade up all pixels one color
}

void fade(uint32_t r, uint32_t g, uint32_t b, uint32_t wait) {
  int i, j;
  for (j=0; j < 384; j++) {
    for (i=0; i < strip.numPixels(); i++) {
      strip.setPixelColor(i, strip.Color((r*j)/1000,(g*j)/1000,(b*j)/1000));
    }
  strip.show();
  }
  delay(wait);
}

void turnAllOn(uint32_t c, uint32_t wait) {
  int i;  
  for (i=0; i < strip.numPixels(); i++) {
    strip.setPixelColor(i, c);  // turn all pixels on
  }
  strip.show();   // write all the pixels out
  delay(wait); 
}

uint32_t Wheel(uint16_t WheelPos)
{
  byte r, g, b;
  switch(WheelPos / 128)
  {
    case 0:
      r = 127 - WheelPos % 128;   //Red down
      g = WheelPos % 128;      // Green up
      b = 0;                  //blue off
      break; 
    case 1:
      g = 127 - WheelPos % 128;  //green down
      b = WheelPos % 128;      //blue up
      r = 0;                  //red off
      break; 
    case 2:
      b = 127 - WheelPos % 128;  //blue down 
      r = WheelPos % 128;      //red up
      g = 0;                  //green off
      break; 
  }
  return(strip.Color(r,g,b));
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently, your fade function is starting at 0 and effectively interpolating up to the desired colour. To fade between colours, you would need the sketch to remember the previous colour it used, and start fading from that instead of from 0.

The approach I'd use is to start by calculating how much each component needs to change by on each step. For example, if you want to fade from 100 to 200 across 50 steps, then it needs to change by +2 on every step. If you wanted to do the same in reverse (200 to 100) then it would have to change by -2.

One of the problems is that each component will probably be changing by a different amount (red might go from 0 to 200, but blue might only go from 50 to 70). If you're using integers all the time then it could result in some uneven transitions, so I'd recommend using floating point instead. It's technically slower (less efficient), but probably not enough to worry about.

This is how I'd probably write it:

```
void fade(uint8_t oldR, uint8_t oldG, uint8_t oldB, uint8_t newR, uint8_t newG, uint8_t newB, uint32_t numSteps, uint32_t waitPerStep)
{
    // Guard against division by zero
    if (numSteps == 0) numSteps = 1;

    // Calculate how how much each colour needs to change on each step
    const float
        stepR = (newR - oldR) / (float)numSteps,
        stepG = (newG - oldG) / (float)numSteps,
        stepB = (newB - oldB) / (float)numSteps;

    // These values will store our colours on the way along
    float r = oldR, g = oldG, b = oldB;
    uint8_t byteR = oldR, byteG = oldG, byteB = oldB;

    // Go through each fade step
    const uint16_t numPixels = strip.numPixels();
    for (uint32_t step = 0; step < numSteps; ++step) {
        // Move one step towards the target colour
        r += stepR;
        g += stepG;
        b += stepB;

        // Round the colours to integers here so we don't have to do it repeatedly in the loop below
        byteR = (uint8_t)(r + 0.5f);
        byteG = (uint8_t)(g + 0.5f);
        byteB = (uint8_t)(b + 0.5f);

        // Apply the colour to each pixel
        for (uint16_t pixel = 0; pixel < numPixels; ++pixel) {
            strip.setPixelColor(pixel, byteR, byteG, byteB);
        }

        strip.show();
        delay(waitPerStep);
    }
}
```

As you can see, you pass it the old colour (which you're fading *from*) and the new colour (which you're fading *to*). As I mentioned above, this means your sketch has to remember which colour it previously used, as I don't think the library provides a way to read the current colour back.

I've included some optimisations in there to make it run faster. There's more you could do to optimise it even further, if necessary.

To use this, you'd do something like this:

```
// Fade from black to red and pause briefly
fade(0, 0, 0,  255, 0, 0,  100, 10);
delay(500);

// Fade from red to purple and pause briefly
fade(255, 0, 0,   255, 0, 255,  100, 10);
delay(500);

// Fade from purple to green and pause briefly
fade(255, 0, 255,  0, 255, 0,  100, 10);
delay(500);
```

I've made a couple of other changes compared to your own fade function function. First of all, I've made it so that you can set the number of steps to fade over. This can be quite useful because bigger colour changes will need more steps to look smooth.

I've also modified the `wait` parameter. In your code, you put the delay after the entire fade was complete, which seems like an odd approach. It makes more sense to allow a small delay between each step of the fade, so you can control how fast it goes.

In my example above, you can see the `100, 10` parameters at the end of each call to `fade()`. That means it will divide the colour change into 100 steps, with a delay of 10ms between each step. The result is that each fade will take roughly 1 second (not counting the time taken to actually update the LED strip).

Comment: Very well answered. Kudos for all code details, optimizations and explanations. Maybe a small bug: the from color never appears as you start your loop with the first step increment. You should add one more iteration and increment only at the end of the loop.

Comment: @jfpoilpret Thanks. Missing out the first step is actually deliberate. Based on the question, I'm assuming the LEDs are already showing the 'old' colour before `fade()` is called. You're absolutely right though. In other circumstances you may indeed want that extra step.

Comment: This is really great. Thanks so much for the detailed write up!